# Why I am not receiving notifications in my "recent inbox messages"?

Tags: bug

Not talking about e-mail notifications or so. I answered a question today ([why is "export PATH" displayed in terminal as a title?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593530/why-is-export-path-displayed-in-terminal-as-a-title)), I was wondering if I could place a bounty on it right now, and opened it.

Surprise!!, surprise!! question had been answered 2 hours ago and I did not receive any notification on the "recent inbox message" tool.

### Screenshot of the "Recent Inbox Message" tool:

[image: Recent Inbox Message]

### Screenshot of the answer just rigth after I upvoted it and accepted (and commented):

[image: Answer]

Am I forgetting something?, is this a stackexchange issue?, is it just me?.

Comment: NOTE: I went and tested this with [Mateo](http://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo) answering it to assist in repeating this bug via [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/594037/se-bug-test-do-not-delete) (10k+ or mods only).  I was unable to reproduce this bug, as I was able to get an answer notification when it was answered.  Because it's not related to the actual site, though, the q is now deleted.  What browser are you using and such?

Comment: @ThomasW. Ok, thanks for replying, the browser I am using is Chromium Version 33.0.1750.152 in Kubuntu 14.04, I have to say this have been working properly I have had no weird situations (this issue happened as well in Windows 8.1, Firefox <don't know what version>). Is the browser related to the issue?.

Comment: Not that I know of but I'm not a dev here.